# My axios response in console.log is an array but my php page keeps saying null

Tags: php, reactjs

```
const sendContact = () => {
          var data = {name: values.name, email: values.email, phone: values.phone, message: values.message}
          var formData = new FormData()
          for(var key in data){
            formData.append(key, data[key]);
          }
          for(let value of formData.values()){
            console.log(value)
          }
          axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/contactForm.php`, formData
          )
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
          
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          })
        
        }
```

my php

```
        <?php
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
        
        
            $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
        
            $data = json_decode($json, true);
        
            var_dump($data);
        
            print_r($data);
        
            print_r($_POST);
        
            echo "Hello World";
        ?>
```

my php page result

```
        NULL Array ( ) Hello World
```

my react page console.log result

```
        {data: 'NULL\nArray\n(\n    [name] => blacrypt\n    [email] =>…sage] => NULL Array ( ) Hello World\n)\nHello World', status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
        ContactForm.jsx:141 NULL
        Array
        (
            [name] => blacrypt
            [email] => hojb@doe.com
            [phone] => 08079132442
            [message] => NULL Array ( ) Hello World
        )
        Hello World
```

Comment: Is the question, *message is null*? because adding var_dump, print_r, `echo "Hello World";` and other non json output to the response won't actually help you debug, massage is not Array, that's the output from `print_r($_POST);`. $_POST is empty due to you using xhr

Comment: What do you get if you use `var_dump($json);`?

Comment: string(0) "" Array ( ) Hello World

Comment: What makes you think your PHP script would be _receiving_ JSON? You added properties to a `FormData` instance, so this should send as normal `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: _"my php page result"_ - what does that even _mean_ here, _where_ exactly did you check this? _"my react page console.log result"_ - you got a non-empty array directly before the `Hello World` line there, so presumably that would be the result of `print_r($_POST);`, meaning `$_POST` was properly filled exactly as to be expected.

Comment: i get my result in the browsers console but when i go to my php page to display the result the array is empty